# XPath - Get node with no child of specific type

Tags: xpath

XML: `<A><B></B></A>` or `<A></A>`

I want to get all `A` nodes that do not have any `B` children.

I've tried

```
/A[not(B)]  
/A[not(exists(B))]
```

without success

I prefer a solution with the syntax `/*[local-name()="A" and .... ]`, if possible. Any ideas that works?

Clarification. The xml looks like:

```
<WhatEver>
  <A>
    <B></B>
  </A>
</WhatEver>
```

or

```
<WhatEver>
  <A></A>
</WhatEver>
```

Comment: Without seeing your XML I would say that "/A[not(B)]" is the way to go. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Also, there should be only one root element, so you're either getting all your XML back or none.

Maybe `//A[not(B)] or /*/A[not(B)]`?

Comment: With the "abstract" syntax /A/B, first line after "XML:", I meant <A><B>,just as Tomalak and alamar thought.

Comment: or <A><B><B><A> or <A><A> to be exact.

Comment: Sorry, of course with endings <A><B></B></A> or <A></A>.

Comment: @Martin Bring: I think your confusion comes from this: When you use an absolute path, the "/" is not the document element ("WhatEver" in your case). It is the document *root*, consequently it needs to be either "/WhatEver/A[not(B)]" or "//A[not(B)]".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Maybe 
`*[local-name() = 'A' and not(descendant::*[local-name() = 'B'])]`?

Also, there should be only one root element, so for `/A[...]` you're either getting all your XML back or none. Maybe `//A[not(B)]` or `/*/A[not(B)]`?

I don't really understand why `/A[not(B)]` doesn't work for you.

```
~/xml% xmllint ab.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <A id="1">
            <B/>
    </A>
    <A id="2">
    </A>
    <A id="3">
            <B/>
            <B/>
    </A>
    <A id="4"/>
</root>
~/xml% xpath ab.xml '/root/A[not(B)]'
Found 2 nodes:
-- NODE --
<A id="2">
    </A>
-- NODE --
<A id="4" />
```

Comment: I can confirm, /A[not(B)] doesn't always work as advertised. I have an example using Xalan in XMLspear where 

    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($theFields)/*[name()='field'][not(child::*[name()='disabled'])]">
    [DO STUFF HERE]
    </xsl:for-each>

produces different output from 
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($FLD)/field[not(disabled)]">
    [DO STUFF HERE]
    </xsl:for-each>

In fact, in the same situation, using
    select="exsl:node-set($theFields)/*[name()='field']"

produces output, but 
   select="exsl:node-set($theFields)/field"

doesn't at all.

Comment: @MichaelKupietz why don't you create a new question about that?

Comment: At some point, when I have time to whittle a huge XSLT down to a minimum working demonstration, I may. At this point, though, I was just responding to the comment implying that /A(not[B]) ought to do what the OP says it doesn't, simply because I observed the same thing OP did.  Evidently, it doesn't, at least, not always. That confirmation might spare some future reader of this page some confusion.

Answer (score 25):

Try this `"/A[not(.//B)]"` or this `"/A[not(./B)]"`.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to education/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 12):

The first `/` causes XPath to start at the root of the document, I doubt that is what you intended.

Perhaps you meant `//A[not(B)]` which would find all `A` nodes in the document at any level that do not have a direct `B` child.

Or perhaps you are already at a node that contains `A` nodes in which case you just want `A[not(B)]` as the XPath.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get A anywhere in the hierarchy from the root, this works (for xslt 1.0 as well as 2.0 in case its used in xslt)

```
//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'a' and not(count(b))]
```

OR you can also do

```
//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'a' and not(b)]
```

OR also

```
//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'a' and not(child::b)]
```

There are n no of ways in xslt to achieve the same thing.

Note: XPaths are case-sensitive, so if your node names are different (which I am sure, no one is gonna use A, B), then please make sure the case matches.

Comment: FYI, the question is about XPath, not XSLT. They are distinct (though related) technologies. Otherwise, your answer is technically correct. As an aside though, "/root/A[not(B)]" works just fine as @Alamar mentioned. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I meant xpaths in my last line. Have edited the post. As for "/root/A[not(B)]" I already ran it successfully. But yet posted alternate xpaths as it wasnt working for Martin. Which is also y i mentioned case-sensitivity.

Comment: How would one select all A with immediate children **other than** B? (A and all child nodes, as long as they contain one or more B elements only)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
/*[local-name()='A' and not(descendant::*[local-name()='B'])]
```