# Delete XML repeated tags

Tags: java, xml, tags

I'm recieving some xml like this :

```
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be29583cba3b">
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be2a36aec2df">
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be3d125bdc1c">Some Text
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
<p>random text</p>
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be29583cba3b">
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be2a36aec2df">
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be3d125bdc1c">
More text
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
```

As you see, I'm having more than 1 tag for the same value, and I just need only 1 tag per text :

```
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be3d125bdc1c">Some Text</cite>
<p>random text</p>
<cite id="0ac50429-bfbd-74e5-81bf-be29583cba3b">More text</cite>
```

But I can't find a good way to get rid of this.  Anyone has a clue? I've tried to get the last child, but I just can't get them.  I've tried with regex, I can get the last node, but I can't replace them correctly , in order to get the desire xml. 
Ty!

This is my solution (I can't anwser my own question , so I write it here instead :)

I know it isn't the best and can be done better, it works.

```
private static String replaceNodes(String simpleRegex, String xml)
{

    String tagMultiple;
    String expresionRegular = "("+simpleRegex+")+";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expresionRegular);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);


    while(matcher.find())  // Here we look for all the nodes that are repeated . EJ  <cite id="asda"><cite id="asda"><cite id="asda">
    {
         Pattern patternSimple = Pattern.compile(simpleRegex);
        Matcher matcherSimple = patternSimple.matcher(xml);
        String tagUnicoEnd ="";
        if (matcherSimple.find()) //Here we get only one node. <cite id="asda">
            tagUnicoEnd = matcher.group(1);         

        tagMultiple = matcher.group();                  
        xml =xml.replace(tagMultiple,tagUnicoEnd);  //we replace all the repetead nodes, with the unique one.
    }       

    return xml;                         
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a XPath solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862239/xpath-get-node-with-no-child-of-specific-type

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way, I know it isn't the best and can be done better

```
private static String replaceNodes(String simpleRegex, String xml)
{

    String tagMultiple;
    String expresionRegular = "("+simpleRegex+")+";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expresionRegular);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);


    while(matcher.find())  // Here we look for all the nodes that are repeated . EJ  <cite id="asda"><cite id="asda"><cite id="asda">
    {
         Pattern patternSimple = Pattern.compile(simpleRegex);
        Matcher matcherSimple = patternSimple.matcher(xml);
        String tagUnicoEnd ="";
        if (matcherSimple.find()) //Here we get only one node. <cite id="asda">
            tagUnicoEnd = matcher.group(1);         

        tagMultiple = matcher.group();                  
        xml =xml.replace(tagMultiple,tagUnicoEnd);  //we replace all the repetead nodes, with the unique one.
    }       

    return xml;                         
}
```