# How to select only leaf nodes with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am looking for some advices on how it could be done. I'm trying a solution only with xpath:

An html example:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>text div (leaf)</div>
    <p>text paragraph (leaf)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>text paragraph 2 (leaf)</p>
```

Code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("- the html above -")
result = doc.xpath("*[not(child::*)]")


[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3febf50f9328 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3febf519b718 "text paragraph 2 (leaf)">]>]
```

But this xpath only gives me the last "p". What I want is like a flatten behavior, only returning the leaf nodes.

Here are some reference answers in stackoverflow:

[How to select all leaf nodes using XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926589/how-to-select-all-leaf-nodes-using-xpath-expression)

[XPath - Get node with no child of specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862239/xpath-get-node-with-no-child-of-specific-type)

Thanks

Comment: what are the values you want?

Comment: All nodes with (leaf) on the text

Comment: @Luccas: Do you want just the text, or do you want the containing element as well? i.e. do you want `text paragraph (leaf)` or `<p>text paragraph (leaf)</p>`? And if you want just the text, do you want all the text nodes separately, or do you simply want all the text concantenated as a single string?

Comment: The reason your attempt failed was because you used `xpath('*…')` instead of `xpath('.//*…')`; see [this bug report](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/213) and [this one](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/572).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is the statement:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("- the html above -")
```

See here:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<END_OF_HTML
<div>
  <div>
    <div>text div (leaf)</div>
    <p>text paragraph (leaf)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>text paragraph 2 (leaf)</p>
END_OF_HTML


doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
#doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
results = doc.xpath("//*[not(child::*)]")
results.each {|result| puts result}

--output:--
<div>text div (leaf)</div>
<p>text paragraph (leaf)</p>
<p>text paragraph 2 (leaf)</p>
```

If I run this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
results = doc.xpath("//*[not(child::*)]")
results.each {|result| puts result}
```

I get no output.

Comment: See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/213 and https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/572

Answer (score 7):

You can find all element nodes that have no child elements using:

```
//*[not(*)]
```

Example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-end
<div>
  <div>
    <div>text div (leaf)</div>
    <p>text paragraph (leaf)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>text paragraph 2 (leaf)</p>
end

puts doc.xpath('//*[not(*)]').length
#=> 3

doc.xpath('//*[not(*)]').each do |e|
    puts e.text
end
#=> "text div (leaf)"
#=> "text paragraph (leaf)"
#=> "text paragraph 2 (leaf)"
```

Answer (score 2):

In XPath, the text itself is a node - so given your comment you would only want to select the tag contents, not the tags containing the content - but you would capture a `<br/>` (if there was one).

I guess you're looking for **all elements not containing other elements** (tags) (which is not *exactly* what you've been asking for) - then you're fine with @Justin Ko's answer and use the XPath expression

```
//*[not(*)]
```

If you really want to look for **all leaf nodes**, you cannot use the `*` selector, but need to use `node()`:

```
//node()[not(node())]
```

Nodes can be elements, but also text nodes, comments, processing instructions, attributes and even XML documents (but those cannot occur within other elements).

If you'd really only want the **text nodes**, go for `//text()` like @Priti proposed, which indeed somewhat selects *exactly the nodes you're asking for* (by highlighting them, not by what leaf nodes are defined as).