# Equivalent of which in scraping?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to run some scraping where the action I take on a node is conditional on the contents of the node.

This should be a minimal example:

```
XML =
'<td class="id-tag">
    <span title="Really Long Text">Really L...</span>
</td>
<td class="id-tag">Short</td>'

page = read_html(XML)
```

Basically, I want to extract `html_attr(x, "title")` if `<span>` exists, otherwise just get `html_text(x)`.

Code to do the first is:

```
page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//td[@class="id-tag"]/span') %>% html_attr("title")
# [1] "Really Long Text"
```

Code to do the second is:

```
page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//td[@class="id-tag"]') %>% html_text
# [1] "\n    Really L...\n" "Short"
```

The real problem is that the `html_attr` approach doesn't give me any `NA` or something similar for the nodes that don't match (even if I let the `xpath` just be `'//td[@class="id-tag"]'` first to be sure I've narrowed down to only the relevant nodes first. This destroys the order -- I can't tell automatically whether the original structure had `"Really Long Text"` at the first or the second node.

(I thought of doing a join, but the mapping between the abbreviated text and the full text is not one-to-one/invertible).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971067/is-there-an-if-then-else-statement-in-xpath) seems to be on the right path -- an if/else construction within the `xpath` -- but doesn't work.

Ideally I'd get the output:

```
# [1] "Really Long Text" "Short"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [R Conditional evaluation when using the pipe operator %>%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604107/r-conditional-evaluation-when-using-the-pipe-operator), you can do something like

```
page %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath='//td[@class="id-tag"]') %>% 
   {ifelse(is.na(html_node(.,xpath="span")), 
           html_text(.),
           {html_node(.,xpath="span") %>% html_attr("title")}
   )}
```

I think it is possibly simple to discard the pipe and save some of the objects created along the way

```
nodes <- html_nodes(page, xpath='//td[@class="id-tag"]')
text <- html_text(nodes)
title <- html_attr(html_node(nodes,xpath='span'),"title")
value <- ifelse(is.na(html_node(nodes, xpath="span")), text ,title)
```

An xpath only approach might be

```
page %>% 
 html_nodes(xpath='//td[@class="id-tag"]/span/@title|//td[@class="id-tag"][not(.//span)]') %>%
 html_text()
```

Comment: I think the fact that `html_node` returns `NA` for branches that don't have any match is what I was most in need of here, thanks!

Comment: And that joint `xpath` is a beast! Could you elaborate on what the `[not(.//span)]` bit is doing? I mainly don't understand the surrounding `[]`, I think?

Comment: @MichaelChirico , it was based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862239/xpath-get-node-with-no-child-of-specific-type, without the wrapping `[]` you get a syntax error (this part is looking for node td with class = id-tag but without a child node "span")

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

XML <- '
<td class="id-tag">
    <span title="Really Long Text">Really L...</span>
</td>
<td class="id-tag">Short</td>
'

pg <- read_html(XML)

html_nodes(pg, "td[class='id-tag']") %>%
  map_chr(function(x) {
    if (xml_find_first(x, "boolean(.//span)")) {
      x <- html_nodes(x, xpath=".//span/@title")
    }
    html_text(x)
  })

## [1] "Really Long Text" "Short"
```