# Reading in html with R rvest. How do I check if a CSS selector class contains anything?

Tags: r, xpath, css-selectors, rvest

this is my first attempt to deal with HTML and CSS selectors.  I am using the R package rvest to scrap the Billboard Top 100 website.  Some of the data that I am interested in include this weeks rank, song, weather or not the song is New, and weather or not the song has any awards.

I am able to get the song name and rank with the following:

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2017-09-30"

webpage <- read_html(URL)
current_week_rank <- html_nodes(webpage, '.chart-row__current-week')
current_week_rank <- as.numeric(html_text(current_week_rank))
```

My problem comes with the new and award indicators.  The songs are listed in rows with each of the 100 contained in:

```
<article> class="chart-row char-row--1 js chart-row" ....
</article>
```

If a song is new, this  will have class within it like:

```
<div class="chart-row__new-indicator">
```

If a song has an award, there will be this class within it:

```
<div class="chart-row__award-indicator">
```

Is there a way that I can look at all 100 instances of the  class="chart-row char-row--1 js chart-row" ... and see if either of these exist within it?  The output that I get from the current_week_rank is one column of 100 values.  I am hoping that there is a way to get this so that I have one observation for each song.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: please share an example URL, it's not completely clear the structure of the page.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The URL is http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2017-09-30

Comment: You can try `... %>% html_attr('class')`, which will return you a character vectors of the class of the tag. Then, check if any specific css class name is in the string.

Comment: Working on a solution now, but this is basically along the lines of this previous question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708685/equivalent-of-which-in-scraping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically amounts to a tailored version of the Q&A I indicated above. I can't tell for 100% certain whether the `or` is working as intended, since there's only one row in your example page with a `<div class="chart-row__new-indicator">`, and that row also happens to have a `<div class="chart-row__award-indicator">` tag as well.

```
#xpath to focus on the 100 rows of interest
primary_xp = '//div[@class="chart-row__primary"]'
#xpath which subselects rows you're after
check_xp = paste('div[@class="chart-row__award-indicator" or' ,
                     '@class="chart-row__new-indicator"]')

webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath = primary_xp) %>% 
  #row__primary for which there are no such child nodes
  #  will come back NA, and hence so will html_attr('class')
  html_node(xpath = check_xp) %>% 
  #! is a bit extraneous, as it only flips FALSE to TRUE
  #  for the rows you're after (necessity depends on
  #  particulars of your application)
  html_attr('class') %>% is.na %>% `!`
```

FWIW, you *may* be able to shorten `check_xp` to the following:

```
check_xp = 'div[contains(@class, "indicator")]'
```

Which certainly covers both `"chart-row__award-indicator"` and `"chart-row__new-indicator"`, but would also wrap up other nodes with a `class` containing `"indicator"`, if such an alternative tag exists (you'll have to determine this for yourself)