# XML Xpath get last children of an element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Stat name="outer">
   <Stat>
      ....
       <Stat name="inner1"></Stat>
       <Stat name="inner2"></Stat>
       <Stat name="inner3"></Stat>
      ....
   </Stat>
</Stat>
```

How can i get all the inner Stat node elements? Between **outer** and the **inner** children in can be any number of Stat node elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//Stat[not(Stat)]`, i.e. a `Stat` node without any `Stat` children.

Variant of [How to select all leaf nodes using XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3926589/5221149)
See also [XPath - Get node with no child of specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/862239/5221149)